# How to add Parent node if Child node elements are equal?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am having very large set of xml data. So in that `"SECTION"` contains `"Piece"` node and they have equal values for `"SECTION name="RF1WB-1"`, `SECTION name="RF1WB-2"`, `SECTION name="RF1WB-3"`. So I want to add `"Parent"`  as parent node to them if `"Piece"` tag contains same values as shown in the second XML.

How to add parent node if the child node elements contain same values?

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("..\\MFAB1.xml");        
XmlNodeList xnList = doc.SelectNodes("MFAB.ini/SECTION");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
    if (xn.HasChildNodes)
    {
        foreach (XmlNode item in xn.SelectNodes("Piece"))
        {
            if (xn.ChildNodes[0].InnerText.ToString().Contains(s3))
            {
                d1.Piece = xn.ChildNodes[0].InnerText.ToString();
            }
            ______________
            ______________
            ______________
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Input file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MFAB.ini>
 <SECTION name="RF1WB-1">
    <Piece>
      RF1-1
    </Piece>
</SECTION>
  <SECTION name="RF1WB-2">
    <Piece>
      RF1-1
    </Piece>
</SECTION>
  <SECTION name="RF1WB-3">
    <Piece>
      RF1-1
    </Piece>
  </SECTION>
  <SECTION name="RF1-2WB-1">
    <Piece>
      RF1-2
    </Piece>
 </SECTION>
  <SECTION name="RF1-2WB-2">
    <Piece>
      RF1-2
    </Piece>
 </SECTION>
</MFAB.ini>
```

---

**Expected output file:**

What I need is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MFAB.ini>
<Parent name = "RF1-1">
 <SECTION name="RF1-1WB-1">
    <Piece>
      RF1-1
    </Piece>
</SECTION>
  <SECTION name="RF1-1WB-2">
    <Piece>
      RF1-1
    </Piece>
</SECTION>
  <SECTION name="RF1-1WB-3">
    <Piece>
      RF1-1
    </Piece>
  </SECTION>
</Parent>
<Parent name = "RF1-2">
  <SECTION name="RF1-2WB-1">
    <Piece>
      RF1-2
    </Piece>
 </SECTION>
  <SECTION name="RF1-2WB-2">
    <Piece>
      RF1-2
    </Piece>
 </SECTION>
</Parent>
</MFAB.ini>
```

Comment: So you are looking to group your data based on your own algorithm?

Comment: yes. Tried LINQ also but no luck. depending on the "Piece" node element need Parent to be added to it. Yes, classes are defined for them. I am getting all the data and elements also. Only need to add "Parent" tag for it. thank you.

Comment: And you group them by Piece? Do you have any classes defining your xml?

Comment: yes, i updated them now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group element by `<Piece>` tag and then put them as child of `<Parent>` tag this way:

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(@"input file");

var result = new XElement(xml.Root.Name, xml.Root.Attributes().ToArray(),
    xml.Root.Elements().GroupBy(x => x.Element("Piece").Value.Trim()).Select(x =>
        new XElement("Parent", new XAttribute("name", x.Key), x))
    );

result.Save(@"output file");
```

Comment: throwing null reference exception at "x.Element("Piece").Value.Trim())"

Comment: Exactly tested using your input file and works properly. If it throws null reference exception, it means the file you are testing, is different from what you shared with us and for example there is an element without having `Piece` tag or having null value for the tag.

Comment: @MadhuKumar Just adding `x.Element("Piece")?.Value?.trim()` should be enough I guess ;)

Comment: @Icepickle It would be enough technically, but it means the file have some problems and can not be grouped by `Piece`.

Comment: True, or it means his specification wasn't specific enough :) In any case, it would allow him to handle the null values as an extra parent :) Sure it can still be grouped, just the name attribute of the parent would be null

Comment: @Icepickle Yes, with this specification you are right :)

Comment: Yes, this code should work. And if Piece tag is not present it need to be skipped. That need to be added. That's it. Also without saving again as output file. I am using foreach with XmlNode. thank you. Will try for it.

Comment: @MadhuKumar Then you just need to add `Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Element(("Piece")?.Value) )` in front of the `GroupBy` statement

Answer (score 1):

To make it easier for yourself, you could use the `XmlSerializer` to read your data, and you could define a dto for your Xml like so

```
[XmlRoot("MFAB.ini")]
public class Mfab {
    [XmlElement("SECTION")]
    public Section[] Sections { get; set; }
}

public class Section {
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Piece")]
    [XmlText]
    public string Piece { get; set; }
}
```

This would read your document as is, having all your sections as part of your Mfab class (sorry, I didn't know a better name for the classes ;) )

This Xml, you could then read like this

```
private static T GetXmlFromFile<T>(string filename) {
    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        return (T)xs.Deserialize(fs);
    }
}
```

Which would give you one class containing all the sections. Now, since you want to reformat your data, you should create a new class that will hold the parent sections, and then a new xml root to hold those as well

```
[XmlRoot("MFAB.ini")]
public class MfabWithParents {
    [XmlElement("PARENT")]
    public ParentSection[] Parents { get; set; }
}

public class ParentSection {
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("SECTION")]
    public Section[] Sections { get; set; }
}
```

The `ParentSection` still reuses the `Section` class created before.

Now to do the transformation, we can implement the following steps

```
// get the xml from a file
var source = GetXmlFromFile<Mfab>(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "data.xml"));
// group all the sections by it's Piece
var groupedSections = source.Sections.GroupBy(section => section.Piece);
// convert the sections from the Grouped section to a parent section with name as attribute
var parentSections = groupedSections.Select(grp => new ParentSection
{
    Name = grp.Key,
    Sections = grp.ToArray()
}).ToArray();
// save the xml to a new file (which could now be read with the MfabWithParents class)
SaveToXml(new MfabWithParents { Parents = parentSections }, Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "data2.xml"));
```

And the save method then looks like this

```
private static void SaveToXml(object data, string filename) {
    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(data.GetType());
    using (var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)) {
        xs.Serialize(fs, data);
    }
}
```